# I cannot make the command successfully run on Slash Command

Tags: python, discord, bots, python-imaging-library, nextcord

This code is failing, I need to make it work for slash command.

It is works only for standard (legacy) commands, but it is refusing to complete in Slash Commands.

Tried: To make slash command appear, where you need to redeem the message and it appears on image.

Expected: ValueError: SlashCommandOption interaction of command SlashApplicationCommand dog_message <function dog_message at 0x000001B202B0D940> Type `<class 'nextcord.interactions.Interaction'>` isn't a supported typehint for Application Commands.

```
@bot.slash_command(name="dog_message", description="Message and share to your friends!", guild_ids=[serverID])
async def furry_message(*args, interaction: Interaction, msg:str):
    msg = " ".join(args)
    img = Image.open("dog.png")
    font = ImageFont.truetype("PatrickHand-Regular.ttf", 50)

    cx, cy = (200, 300)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((cx, cy), msg, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
    img.save("dog_edited.png")

    with open("furry_message.png", "rb") as f:
        img = file(f)
        await interaction.response.send_message(file=img)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe U should switch the order of the arguments so interaction would be first. Also, I think but I am not sure args should be removed as msg is a string so I guess it should include everything after the command in a single string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the `*arg` parameter. Just put the `interaction` and the `msg`